# Understanding Upstart script stanza

Tags: upstart

I have a script that runs some java process:

/apps/run_my_app.sh:

```
   #!/bin/sh
   CLASSPATH=foo
   java -cp $CLASSPATH foo.app
```

can I have an Upstart script stanza like this?

```
script
    /apps/run_my_app.sh
end script
```

If so, do I need an?

> expect fork

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that if you want to.

Regarding 'expect fork', it depends what your particular JVM and Java app is doing. Upstart needs to know how many times your service forks. Please see:

- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#expect
- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#run-a-java-application